# Unable to continue with rebase due to untracked working tree files would be overwritten by merge error

Tags: git

I'm currently mergin two branches using `git rebase -i`, There is a commit that is not letting me continue with the rebase. When I check the commit I see that there are some files but nothing is conflicting with the branch.

[image]

I tried using the `fixup` and `edit` because I thought maybe I had made some changes, however this is not the case. When I run `git rebase --continue` I get the following message:

```
error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by merge:
```

It also shows files as shown in the image above with the following message

```
Please move or remove them before you merge.
Aborting
hint: Could not execute the todo command
hint: 
hint:     pick 430847f3fe3f80162a93f62db3e016f3c9a97cc1 Include html2text package
hint: 
hint: It has been rescheduled; To edit the command before continuing, please
hint: edit the todo list first:
hint: 
hint:     git rebase --edit-todo
hint:     git rebase --continue
```

What can I do in this case? Does this mean, I can rebase this commit? Do I have to abort?

Comment: merging is not really rebasing...

Comment: are you rebasing a merge commit?

Comment: that is not a `merge` commit, is the integration of a package. But im confused as to why is not letting me continue with the rebase.

Comment: well, git is quite explicit with the problem, you have untracked file that will probably be overwritten by the next cherry-pick, thus it stops. If you may archive those files and erase them before be able to go on

Comment: But I don't see those file in the folder it says the are. There is no `vendor/soundasleep` folder when I check atom so I can't erase them. What you suggest I do in this case?

Comment: Try to do `git reset --hard; git clean -xdf` (be very careful and save backup, since this removes everything which is not tracked or commited).

Comment: if you are sure you have everything backuped in your directory, try a `git clean -fd` __BUT__ be careful it will erase everything that is untracked

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that I had the following in my `.gitignore` file.

`!/vendor/soundasleep`

Therefore, I was unable to continue with the merge and not see the files in my editor. I did the following to add the files.

`git add vendor/soundasleep`

and then I was able to `git rebase --continue`

NOTE: If you encounter this kind of error and you don't see the files in your editor check your `.gitignore` file and add the files or delete them manually. For me since I wanted to keep the changes, I `git add vendor.soundasleep` fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by merge:
> ```

This means exactly what it says: some file(s) exist in your work-tree but not in your index, so they are *untracked*.  Proceeding with the next `git cherry-pick` that is part of the `git rebase` sequence will overwrite them.  (The main tricky bits here are that `git rebase` mainly consists of a series of `git cherry-pick` commands, and that `git cherry-pick` uses Git's merge mechanism, so that even though you're doing a `git rebase` you are getting some files merged.)

> ... But I don't see those file in the folder it says the are. There is no `vendor/soundasleep` folder when I check atom ...

That's the truly puzzling part.  Git definitely sees the files as existing in your work-tree.  Note that if you're on a typical Windows or MacOS system, the underlying file system does case-folding, so if there is a `vendor/SoundAsleep` folder, or a `VENDOR/soundasleep` folder, or anything along those lines, that also counts.

(I don't use the atom editor and would do any inspecting outside it, myself.)

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was because of diff in both `.gitignore` & `.idea` (untracked).
I closed IDE, removed `.idea` folder. Rebase was successfull.